# adding the ("+") to a number only key down event

Tags: javascript

how would i add the + symbol to my number only function
to allow the user to insert +227 728 3389 into the text box
at the moment the user can insert anything from 0 to 9 and no A to Z letters can be used but now i want to allow 0 to 9 as well as 0 to 9 and + symbols:

```
//my function is as follows:

function numbersOnly(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if(charCode > 31 &&(charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
            return true;


}
```

Comment: Seems like a good solution for regex.

Comment: I would not bother trying to enforce this with keydown events. Just do a little input validation. If you are confortable with using html5, something like `<input type="tel" pattern="\+[0-9]{10}">` can do the trick. Make sure you always do input validation on the server as well. If you still want to go with the keydown event, why don't you 'pull' the + in front of the input field (`+<input type="text">`). You can add that + to your value on the server side later if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that blocks input if the character is not a digit or a plus:

```
var KeyCode = {
  ZERO : 48,
  NINE : 57,
  PLUS : 43
}
function isDigit(key) {
  return key >= KeyCode.ZERO && key <= KeyCode.NINE;
}

function numbersOnly(evt) {  
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode

  if (!isDigit(charCode) && charCode !== KeyCode.PLUS){
    return false;
  }
  return true;   
}
```

You might want to update the `isDigit` function if you allow the use of the NumPad (96-108 keycodes)

Comment: its not working here is a js fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/viralpatel/nSjy7/

Comment: can you try and update the example in the fiddle please

Comment: I updated the answer with the correctly observed value for the PLUS key. Please test it on the devices/browsers you are interested in. Also, read Sumurai8's comment as it is probably a much better way to do it. Furthermore, the recommended input type for a telephone number is 'tel', not 'number'.